# UTF-8 charset issue with loadHTMLFile

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm modifying an html file with php with `loadHTML()` php function:

```
$html = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html->loadHTMLFile('../fr/index.html');
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
...(do something)...
$html->saveHTMLFile("../fr/foo.html");
```

On my localhost, the saved file is fine. It actually converts utf-8 special characters (I don't know why) to `&eacute`-like characters and modify the indentation of the html file but it works.

Problem is, it doesn't work on my hosting server. For instance, I got `&Atilde;&acute;` instead of `&ocirc;` (french characters)

My localhost and the hosting server run with 5.6 php version and my html file has these metas:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a web application software developer you should learn to use linux and the lamp environment. You using windows and xampp, am i right? This is good for beginners, to learn the first steps of web programming, but further you should try to develop in a lamp environment, so you get no surprises after uploading your files. Ok, right now i would say, synchronize your encoding-preferences on your IDE ( like eclipse ) and try everything again. Otherwise there are not so much informations about your problem, so i make some speculations about. But i believe you get some troubles, cause you are developing on windows for some unix/linux server/hoster. Cheers.

Comment: Mmh thanks for the advice but no! I'm using sublime text on a mac. All my files are utf-8 encoded and it normally works fine.